# How can I make a PSDrive created within a function accessible out of this function?

Tags: .net, powershell

I assume creating a new PS-Drive within a function makes that drive only accessible within that function.

How can I make a PS-Drive created by calling a function from the MAIN accessible out of that function?

```
 $temproraryPSDriveName = "temproraryDrive" 
 Create-PSDriveBy $temproraryPSDriveName #private function simply creates PSDrive based on a logic
 dir $($temproraryPSDriveName + ":") #This does not work as the 'teproraryDrive' is not 
                                     #accessible once I exit the Create-PSDriveBy function
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give global scope to your PSDRIVE:

```
New-PSDrive -Name qq -PSProvider filesystem -Root c:\windows -Scope global
```